# boost & asio as part in big project with Cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

I want to use Boost core libraries (like lambda) and Boost ASIO library in a large cross-platform project built with the Cmake. I want to put Boost & ASIO in my source control tree and build it as part of project with the Cmake. So I don't want to "install" it on computers and link with it.

How can this be done? Does there exist `CMakeLists.txt` for Boost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Boost.Lambda and Boost.ASIO are header-only libraries, so in your CMakeLists.txt file, you could include your Boost `include` directory in the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variable, and when your code is built, the header code will be built into your resulting modules.

For situations where you are using non-header-only libraries, like Boost.Filesystem, then you will have to either ship libraries you built, or modify the experimental CMake version of boost.build, which you can find here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/CMake

**Edit**

I was slightly confused about Boost.Asio. It is not truly header-only, because it depends on Boost.System, and possibly Boost.Thread depending on how you use it.

However, Boost.Asio is derived from Asio ( http://think-async.com/ ), which is header-only.

Comment: so for header only libraries I just drag headers around, without any changes to them (i.e. autotools, configure, m4, stuff like this not neede)?

Comment: @zaharpopov - Yes, for header-only libraries, all the code is provided in the header files (for example, look at the header file for any of the boost smart pointers). When you do the whole `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` and whatnot, the code from those header files will be included into your compile, so you don't have to link external libraries in. Not all Boost libraries are header-only, but many common ones are. More info about header-only libs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only

Comment: @zaharpopov, I have amended my post about ASIO.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project aiming at providing a CMake version of boost. It is quite outdated, but the `CMakeLists.txt` might help you. You can check it out [there](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/CMake).